# How does a language like OCaml implement pattern matching?

Tags: pattern-matching

Say I have a code snippet like so:

```ml
type 'a mylist = | Nil | Cons of 'a * 'a mylist

let rec last l =
    match l with
    | Nil -> None
    | Cons(x, Nil) -> Some(x)
    | Cons(x, xs) -> last xs
```

Obviously, this pattern matches over the constructors of `mylist` - `Nil` and `Cons`.
My question is how you'd go about implementing something like this. You can't just feed values to `Cons` until you find some that match `l`, so i'm assuming the OCaml compiler implements something like a "reverse constructor" that takes a value of type `mylist` and attempts to turn it into the constituent parts?

For example, in psudo-ocaml:

```ml
type 'a mylist = | Nil | Cons of 'a * 'a mylist

Cons : ('a * 'a mylist) -> 'a mylist

UnCons : 'a mylist -> ('a mylist * 'a) option
```

Is this correct, or does it take another approach? What about for, say, haskell or sml?

Comment: There are many options for the low level ("byte-level") representation of data types. An inefficient but simple one could be: a list value is a triple of machine words, `(0,0,0)` for nil and `(1,ptr1,ptr2)` for cons, where `ptr1` and `ptr2` are pointers to the head and the tail. Pattern matching then simply reads the first word (and the first word pointed to by `ptr2`) to test whether we have a match.

Comment: @chi Thank you for the explanation, but i'm specifically interesting in how the listed languages implement it.

Comment: The languages don't implement it at all, they only describe the behaviour such code should have. It's the individual compilers which determine the actual implementation, it even might change from version to version of the same compiler. To get an answer you should look at the code your compiler outputs.

Comment: Here's a paper describing how pattern matching is implemented in OCaml: https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/507669.507641

Comment: @Jake At a basic level, it's pretty much how chi described it. A reference to a value contains enough information (in the reference itself and/or in the referenced structure in memory) that the compiled code can inspect and tell which constructor was used, and where the references to any fields are. Ensuring this property is exactly why constructors need to be treated differently than any other function. In more detail, exactly where information is stored (pointer tags, exact memory layout, etc) differs between systems, so you won't get one common answer for everything you asked about.

Comment: @Jake The more detailed versions are also not really something to cover in the format of a stack overflow post. You're more after detailed technical papers for that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

OCaml uses an uniform representation of values under the hood. Each value is either a tagged integer (for instance `1`) or a pointer to a block (for instance `[|1;2|]`. A block is itself an array containing a tag. When a variant type is defined

```
type t =
 | A
 | B
 | C of int
 | D of int
```

constructors without arguments are represented as tagged integers whereas constructors with arguments are mapped to blocks.
A good way to learn more about this representation is to use the internal `Obj` module which contain functions that manipulate on the memory representation of OCaml values.
For instance, we can peek at the underlying representation of the constructors. First, by checking that

```
Obj.(is_int @@ repr A)
```

returns true. Furthermore, we can also check that `A` is represented as a tagged `0` in memory with:

```
assert (Obj.repr A = Obj.repr 0)
```

Similarly, `C 1` is a block with tag 0 containing an integer in its first field

```
assert Obj.(
  tag @@ repr (C 1) = 0
  && field (repr (C 1)) 0 = repr 1
)
```

With this uniform representation, pattern matching can be compiled into either a decision tree or a backtracking automata.
Looking at your example:

```
type 'a mylist = | Nil | Cons of 'a * 'a mylist

let rec last l =
    match l with
    | Nil -> None
    | Cons(x, Nil) -> Some(x)
    | Cons(x, xs) -> last xs
```

The pattern match can be resumed to:

- check if the argument is `Nil`(aka `0`), then return `None`
- if not check if the second field of the argument is `Nil` (aka `0`), then
  return `Some (first_field of the argument)`
- else call `last (second_field of the argument)`.

You can then compare that idea with the actual OCaml implementation by asking the OCaml compiler to emit its lambda intermediary representation with `ocamlc -dlambda`:

```
(letrec
  (last/271
     (function l/272
       (if l/272
         (if (field_imm 1 l/272) (apply last/271 (field_imm 1 l/272))
           (makeblock 0 (field_imm 0 l/272)))
         0)))
```

Looking closely at this IR, we can observe that the pattern matching has been compiled to two `if`, the first one on the list `l/272` itself, and the second one on `field_imm 1 l/272`, in other words on the second field of `l/2`

Note that in this specific case, there was not many possible optimizations so the compiled IR is quite close to the original pattern match.

However, for more complex `match`, there are quite few layer of optimization to ensure that the generated code is small and efficient by moving around clause, merging or splitting them, and trying to keep as much contextual information as possible when a clause fails.

Currently in 2022, the OCaml compiler implementation mostly follows the algorithm described by https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/507669.507641 for compiling pattern matching to efficient backtracking automata.

Answer (score 6):

[The Spineless Tagless G-machine](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/1992/04/spineless-tagless-gmachine.pdf) (STG machine) is a paper describing the general approach that GHC takes to evaluating expressions. It is quite old, and GHC has moved on from this approach, but it's still interesting as a description of one way to do this stuff that smart people thought was a good idea.

The approach to handling data constructors and case expressions is only one of the topics it covers, though, and it is tough to just provide excerpts from that section without having to summarize all the previous sections as well. But, broadly speaking, every value in the language is represented as a pointer to executable code, and to use that value is to jump to the code it points to. The code pointed to by a Cons will be different than the code pointed to by a Nil, so you get the discrimination that way.

A related thing you might consider: how would you implement cons lists using only functions, with no `type` facility in the language to explicitly define new types? It turns out this can be done for any data type in a fairly mechanical way, by representing a value as a function, where the function expects functions as arguments, one argument per constructor the type has. The nth argument represents "what I want to do if the value is of the nth constructor", and it requires one argument per field that constructor has, to let you get at the values in its fields.

That's a bit hard to follow in prose, so let's look at an example using cons and nil. I'll use Haskell notation, which I'm more familiar with, but the same ideas should be expressible in OCaml. The one part I'm not happy with pedagogically is the newtype at the beginning. It looks like "cheating" by defining a new data type, but it's necessary only at the type level, as a level of indirection to avoid an infinite type. At the term level, it's just a wrapper around a function.

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}

import Prelude hiding (head, tail, last)

newtype List a = List
   (forall r. -- Client can choose any return type
     r -> -- Value to return in case of Nil
     (a -> List a -> r) -> -- Called with Cons's two fields
     r) -- The result

nil :: List a
nil = List (\n c -> n)

cons :: a -> List a -> List a
cons h t = List (\n c -> c h t)

head :: List a -> Maybe a
head (List list) = list Nothing (\h t -> Just h)

tail :: List a -> Maybe (List a)
tail (List list) = list Nothing (\h t -> Just t)
```

`nil` and `cons` are the constructors of this type, and `head` and `tail` are example simple consumers. Observe that `nil` is represented by a function that just returns its first argument, while `cons` is represented by a function that passes its head and tail to its second argument. `head` and `tail` demonstrate how to use a list: each must call their list, passing it two arguments to describe how they want to handle empty and non-empty lists respectively.

How would we implement your `last`? Recursively, of course:

```
last :: List a -> Maybe a
last (List list) = list Nothing (\h t -> Just (go h t))
  where go :: a -> List a -> a
        go curr (List rest) = rest curr go
```

The point of this exercise is to show that there's nothing fundamentally special about data types with multiple constructors or fields - it can all just be seen as syntax sugar over closures and functions. No real language implementation is going to do things as crudely as my example, but the STG machine's approach of treating each value as a function is in some ways just a (much) more sophisticated implementation of this idea.

---

If you've studied design patterns in object-oriented languages, this idea may look suspiciously familiar: it's the Visitor pattern! That's no accident: the Visitor pattern is the analogue of pattern matching. You can use it to simulate pattern matches in languages that don't have any.

Comment: AFAIK, GHC indeed [moved away](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/publication/make-fast-curry-pushenter-vs-evalapply/) from the "push/enter" approach of that original paper, in favor of "eval/apply". Still, the original approach is very interesting, even if it was found to be more complex to implement in practice.